# git status typo: what does the extra space do?

Tags: git

I typed

```
git status - uno
```

and got the response

```
# On branch XYZ_XYZ
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

I knew I had made some changes, so this wasn't right. I then saw the typo... I meant to type

```
git status -uno
```

which gives the correct response:

```
# On branch XYZ_XYZ
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   abcd/xyz.cpp
#       ...
#
```

(Note: `git status -uno` is typically very slow on this system, but in the typo case the response was almost instant.)

What status was git checking when I typed the first command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git status - uno` is an alternative spelling of `git status -- uno`, which can also be spelled `git status uno`. All of these commands check for the status of the `uno` path in your repository. Since one doesn't exist, `git status` is quick in telling you that there is nothing to commit.

git commands that accept optional pathspecs use the `--` separator to disambiguate between pathspecs and arguments that precede them, such as options and branch/commit names. The use of `-` and `--` as separator is a decades-old Unix convention, invented to enable specifying arguments that start with `-`.

Comment: I liked the concept that `-` was an older spelling of `--`.

Comment: @turbulencetoo I believe `--` was introduced by GNU getopt along with `--long-option` syntax, but I'm not 100% sure of the exact history.